# What is tomcat/kerberos realm and where it is configured

Tags: apache, tomcat, ldap, kerberos, jaas

I am configuring spengo/tomcat/sso/ on windows 7.
I dont understand what is a Realm and where it is configured !
From reading the following guides:

1. https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/realm-howto.html
2. https://dzone.com/articles/do-not-publish-configuring-tomcat-single-sign-on-w

I understand a realm is a DB of users/password, This DB data can be taken from several places, DB, Active directory, users.xml file, etc..

When configuring krb5.ini and jaas.config I need to provide a realm name, Where do i find this Realm name, On our Active Directory machine - No system admin ever created a Realm object, So how do i know what is the Realm name to enter in configuration ?
Spengo w/ SSO require JAASRealm, So why I need to setup
Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm In the server.xml ?
Does JAASRealm is a wrappher that uses JNDI in order to work with AD?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I understand a realm is a DB of users/password, This DB data can be taken from several places, DB, Active directory, users.xml file, etc.

It is a service, not just a database. It can be implemented via an XML file, a JNDI interface, a JDBC interface, JAAS, several others.

> When configuring krb5.ini and jaas.config I need to provide a realm name. Where do i find this Realm name

You configure it, in a `Realm` entry in either your context.xml file or, if you want it global across webapps, in server.xml. Then you refer to that name in the files you mention.

> On our Active Directory machine - No system admin ever created a Realm object,

Of course not. They don't exist in AD servers. You're looking in the wrong place.

> So how do i know what is the Realm name to enter in configuration ?

In this case you would use a JNDI or JAAS realm.

> Spengo w/ SSO require JAASRealm

So there's your answer.

> So why I need to setup
>   Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm In the server.xml?

You don't. You need to configure a JAAS realm, as you just said above. Unclear why you think a JNDI realm is required here.

> Does JAASRealm is a wrappher that uses JNDI in order to work with AD?

You need to look some of these things up. JAAS is a service that can use any combination of login modules, including some you can write yourself. What they do is up to them, and to you if you write them. Too broad to answer here.

Comment: If using JAASRealm, where do i set up its name (the one im referring in jaas.conf) ? in apache site they set: Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JAASRealm"
                appName="MyFooRealm"
    userClassNames="org.foobar.realm.FooUser"
     roleClassNames="org.foobar.realm.FooRole"/>
but what should be its name in config ?

Comment: I can't answer this definitively until Saturday as I am away from my sources, but I think you have that back to front. You have to define the Realm itself in one of the two places I mentioned, and in the case of JAASRealm you have to define a configuration file and a configuration name when you do that.

Comment: I have configured the realm name in jaas.config and krb5.ini, I am not sure Tomcat configs (web/server.xml) will recognise the realm name, since it is not defined there, only the class name is defined there as JAASRealm (as they instruct in tomcat documents), The actual realm name in my configs is not JAASRealm, i set it MY.DOM, Maybe you can help via mail to send me part of your working configs ? It will be great

Comment: The `appName` parameter of the JAASRealm must agree with the application name in `jaas.config`, i.e. the name of the applicable configuration block. I don't understand the part about specifying the realm name in `jaas.config`. My configuration wouldn't help you as it involves a third party Tomcat valve as well.

Comment: Actually there are 2 'realm' terms. The one in Tomcat and the one in Kerberos. This makes it a bit confusing.
AD also has a realm when acting as KDC. The realm in AD is identical to the domain (IIRC).

Comment: Well I'm talking about the Tomcat realm, and as far as I can see it doesn't have a name at all.